# How to connect to SQL Server docker container from another container?

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have pulled and run SQL Server 2017 container image using the following command:

```
docker pull microsoft/mssql-server-linux
docker run --name mssql -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=!Abcd123' -p 1433:1433 -d microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

And I also deployed an ASP.NET Core Web API application to a Docker container, using the following commands:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o Output
docker build -t apitest .
docker run -p 3000:80 --name apitest_1 apitest
```

The content of `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
COPY Output /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerSQLTest.dll"]
```

In my Web API application, I have created an Entity Framework Core migration which will create the database and seed some data. In `Configure` method of `Startup` class, I add the following code to apply the pending migrations to the database:

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
                            IHostingEnvironment env, 
                            StudentDbContext dbContext)
{
    await dbContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
    ...
}
```

And the database connection string is retrieved from `appsettings.json` which contains the following section:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost,1433;Database=student;User Id=sa;Password=!Abcd123;"
}
```

But the app cannot run correctly, the exception message:

```
fail: WebApplication6.Startup[0]
  System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<ExistsAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.ExistsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Add `-h mssql` to your `docker run` command. That will allow you to connect to the SQL container by that name (`Server=mssql`).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Docker has a DNS server built in, and containers connect to each other by the **container name**. In your case you named the SQL Server container `mssql` so that's the server name you need to put into your connection string for the .NET app: `Server=mssql;Database=student;User Id=sa;Password=!Abcd123;`.

Check out the [.NET Core album viewer sample on GitHub](https://github.com/dockersamples/dotnet-album-viewer), which uses Docker Compose to define a multi-container app.

Comment: This worked perfectly with the default docker setup in visual studio.  Via container orchestrator support.

Answer (score 19):

I resolved the issue by inspecting container network firstly then find the network IP and put to appsetting.json

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=172.17.0.2;Database=VehicleKey;User Id=sa;Password=p@ssW0rd;"
  }
```

[image: inspect docker network]

find name of SQLSERVER
[image]

Comment: Will this not be a manual operation all the time to find the IP and connecting to it..?
I would prefer the answer above by Elton to use the container name.

Comment: The other answer looks cleaner but the name of the container will not resolve to the dns entry in the bridge. Probably something that I have in my config.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you are using two or more containers, there couldn't be any localhost connections. 
Each docker container has own internal network IP.
Once you started a container with an exposed port to be able to connect to that container you need to specify host IP (where container actually running).

So, as example, you should have next string for connection:

```
Server=192.168.1.99,1433;Database=student;User Id=sa;Password=!Abcd123;
```

where: 192.168.1.99 - actual IP of the host where docker container running.

Answer (score 0):

You must know Docker container Ip address. You can get it executing **ipconfig** in **cmd**

[image: Windows ipconfig]

Use this IP for connection to SQL Server

[image: Connect to Sql Server]

If you are using Linux or Linux installed on WSL execute **ifconfig** from **bash** console

[image: Linux ifconfig]

[image: Connecto to SQL]

In the case when Linux is installed in your local WSL both IP addresses routes to the same SQL Server instance

[image: Two Ip addresses to the same SQL Server Instance]