# Cannot use container name to connect to SQL Server container in containerized Blazor app

Tags: sql-server, docker-compose, blazor

I am trying to learn Docker Compose by creating a simple Todo List app with Blazor. It's a simple solution with just the Blazor app and SQL Server containers. I'm having problems connecting the app to the db.

However, every attempt to query the db results in:
`Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)`

Here's my current `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services: 
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: mssql
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Str0ngP@ssword
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - 1433:1433
    expose:
      - 1433
  blazor_playground:
    image: blazor-playground
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - mssql
```

Now I supply a connection string in `Program.cs`:

```
const string CONNECTION_STRING = "Server=mssql,1433; Database=playground; User Id=sa;Password=Str0ngP@ssword; Integrated Security=false; TrustServerCertificate=True;";
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<TodoContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer(CONNECTION_STRING)
);
```

I can confirm that I can connect to SQL Server with SSMS. It's there that I create the `playground` database and `TodoItems` table if they didn't persist.

Additionally, running just the SQL Server container causes the Blazor app to run fine locally (switching mssql with localhost in the conn string).

According to the [Docker Compose networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), I should just be able to use the `container_name` as the server name, but it's still not working.

I had high hopes that info in here would help, but didn't: [How to connect to SQL Server docker container from another container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926064/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-docker-container-from-another-container)

What can I do to fix this or further troubleshoot?

**UPDATE**
Here's the result of `docker inspect blazorserverplayground_default`:

```
$ docker inspect blazorserverplayground_default
[
    {
        "Name": "blazorserverplayground_default",
        "Id": "bd8d031d4fc7f2d49fa934e0f1beb1f633284ff60a3c0048740f9d367cb15b6e",
        "Created": "2023-01-25T22:51:53.990730099Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.24.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.24.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "9de8742b7f96e0b55109e2141a54652d1403edeb9b3efbafeba8e8c69d45318a": {
                "Name": "blazorserverplayground-blazor_playground-1",
                "EndpointID": "925b031756389ee29fdc037613ea4eb2115891d658e772d25ee4d6dfc1e4d800",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e185c2886c551ad3ca00fe915a59a061ff46878f2dbc55d5924d4b94ad2879d7": {
                "Name": "mssql",
                "EndpointID": "93480cc94dbf21ea08d0123fefccbd7ba30b4e3077b7fef6758552147d6c30c1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:18:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.24.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "blazorserverplayground",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.15.1"
        }
    }
]
```

Looks like the SQL Server container is named properly. Not sure why the DNS won't resolve correctly.

Comment: Try removing the expose definition. You'd normally use either `ports:` to publish container ports on the host, making them accessible to the outside world, or `expose:` to make ports available to other containers in the composition. You shouldn't need to use both.

Comment: If that doesn't work then perhaps there's a DNS issue in the composition's network - would `host.docker.internal` work instead of `mssql`, or if you `docker network inspect` the composition's network, the mssql container's IP address directly?

Comment: I am using ports so I can connect with SSMS and expose so that my app can hopefully connect. Do you know what this DNS issue would be within the composition's network? I would like to do what the docs say I should be able to do.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue also using SQL Server. I was also including the port in the server property of the connection string. Once I removed the port, my web app container was able to connect.

Comment: So use `Server=mssql` instead of `Server=mssql,1433`?

Comment: yes, that is what I did